# Replacing any String that contains "00" or "0" with 00 or 0 (Handling double quotes in SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

My output in a column currently has:

| Pill Type |
| --- |
| "00" Vegetarian Capsules : ( |
| "0" Vegetarian Capsules : ( |
| "0" Gelatin Capsules : ( |
| "DINO" : ( |

I need to replace the entire string with only what is contained between the double quotes, with this being my desired result:

| Pill Type |
| --- |
| 00 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| DINO |

I'm newer to SQL and before would get by doing a CASE statement or even a nested REPLACE() statement to clean up some strings

Now that there are double quotes, too many phrases that would take a long time to write out replacing each one, and needing only what is contained within the double quotes has me stuck and I can't quite figure out a solution.

Comment: So is it just "0 and 00", or "what is contained between the double quotes"?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract string between double quotes in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51539817/extract-string-between-double-quotes-in-sql)

Comment: Do you strings actually contain the double quotes?  Your last example has neither 0 nor 00 in the string, why are you not returning the full string?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a script that demonstrates how you can get the desired result:

```
declare @tmp as table (s nvarchar(100) not null);
insert into @tmp values ('"00" Vegetarian Capsules : (');
insert into @tmp values ('"0" Vegetarian Capsules : (');
insert into @tmp values ('"0" Gelatin Capsules : (');
insert into @tmp values ('"DINO" : (');

select SUBSTRING(s, charindex('"', s) + 1, len(s) - charindex('"', reverse(s)) - charindex('"', s)) from @tmp;
```

However, please be aware that the entire string is the result if no double quote is present. You may use a CASE expression if you need to address this.

Comment: Just what I needed. I was creating a CTE table to join back into my main table, so if in that description of the pill, if the pill size was included (always those double quoted ones) I could include that information clearly in a new column. I copied and pasted your exact SELECT statement and just switched out the column name for mine and it got me there. Thank you!