# SQL Server get all strings between double quotes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Trying to collect values between many double quotes " in SQL Server
I manage to collect when there is only one pair of double quotes.
Ñeed the T-SQL to handle all double quotes, I do not know if I will extract 1, 2 or 30 strings between double quotes.

What I got to work with:

```
DECLARE @testData VARCHAR(250) = 'Task : "Testing Data" started "NOT" successfully. @ Status : "FAILED"' 

SELECT Substring(@testData, Charindex('"', @testData, 1) + 1, 
              Len(@testData) - Charindex('"', @testData) - 
              Charindex('"', Reverse(@testData))) AS [Output];
```

From the string above, goal is to get:

- Testing Data
- NOT
- FAILED

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51539817/extract-string-between-double-quotes-in-sql

Comment: tested quickly seem to do the trick, thanks

Comment: What about double quotes within a string to extract, are those escaped?

Answer (score 0):

additional variat to solution posted in OP comments, avoiding loops:

```
DECLARE @testData VARCHAR(250) = 'Task : "Testing Data" started "NOT" successfully. @ Status : "FAILED"'
DECLARE @delimeter VARCHAR(10) = '"';

;WITH
    tally AS --create sequence 1 to string Length
    (
        SELECT n = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT n +1
        FROM tally
        WHERE n <= LEN(@testData)
    ),
    cte AS
    (
        SELECT T.N , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY T.N ) AS RN
        FROM tally AS T
        WHERE SUBSTRING(@testData, T.N, LEN(@delimeter)) = @delimeter
    )
SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@testData, COALESCE(R.N, LEN(@delimeter), 1),
                            L.N - COALESCE(R.N, LEN(@delimeter), 1)),@delimeter,'') AS part
FROM cte AS L
    LEFT JOIN cte AS R ON L.RN = R.RN+1
WHERE L.RN%2=0
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)
```